# Virtuemart 2.0 Module Shopping Cart, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm, having troubles with the jQuery version that the Virtuemart Shopping cart Module is using. 
I need to load a different version of jQuery. This module is using the following link: `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`. I need to load version 1.9.1.

I have no idea where I can change this link. Does somebody knows where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found it already. I found the answer is on this website: `http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/General_JS-Problems_with_templates_and_jQuery/10/diff`

There is an option in Virtuemart to disable the jQuery Libary. 
Just go to: index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=config. click the Tab Templates and you will find the option to disable jQuery.